# __init__.py", line 92, in <module> raise RuntimeError("Python 3.5 or later is required")

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pip, runtime-error

I am running Python on Visual Studio Code and today when I try to install any packages with `pip`, I get the following:

```
pip install sqlalchemy                            
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python34\Scripts\pip-script.py", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==20.0.2', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 558, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2682, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2355, in load
    return self.resolve()
File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2361, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\pip-20.0.2-py3.4.egg\pip\_internal\cli\main.py", line 10, 
in <module>  
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\pip-20.0.2-py3.4.egg\pip\_internal\cli\autocompletion.py", 
line 9, in <module>  
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\pip-20.0.2-py3.4.egg\pip\_internal\cli\main_parser.py", 
line 7, in <module> 
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\pip-20.0.2-py3.4.egg\pip\_internal\cli\cmdoptions.py", 
line 28, in <module> 
    from pip._internal.models.target_python import TargetPython
File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\pip-20.0.2- 
py3.4.egg\pip\_internal\models\target_python.py", line 4, in <module>
    from pip._internal.utils.misc import normalize_version_info
File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\pip-20.0.2-py3.4.egg\pip\_internal\utils\misc.py", line 
20, in <module> 
    from pip._vendor import pkg_resources
File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\pip-20.0.2- 
py3.4.egg\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 92, in <module>
    raise RuntimeError("Python 3.5 or later is required")
RuntimeError: Python 3.5 or later is required
```

What can I do to deal with this?

Comment: The error message suggests a pretty clear course of action: upgrade to Python 3.5 or later. (Ideally 3.8 at this point.)

Comment: I am already at Python 3.8. Let me check the configs and see what fle the VS Code is pointing at.

Comment: PS C:\Users\bruno\Google Drive\Georgian College\Data_Programing\Final_Project_PY> python3 --version
Python 3.8.2

Comment: Gues this would be the error source:

PS C:\Users\bruno\Google Drive\Georgian College\Data_Programing\Final_Project_PY> python --version
Python 3.4.4

Comment: Yeah, you've got a lingering Python 3.4, and your `pip` is still pointing to that Python.

Comment: Always check your assumptions. Show us the output of `pip -V` and `which pip` to see if it's actually picking up the older install of Python 3.4. Then, fix your path, and retry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell Visual Studio Code which `python` interpreter to use.

By default, it's going to use the system `python`.
[In your case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61051939/init-py-line-92-in-module-raise-runtimeerrorpython-3-5-or-later-is-req#comment108009200_61051939), it got the Python 3.4.4 version.

Open the command palette and select **Python: Select Interpreter**.
Then select the appropriate one from the list:

[image]

You can also manually set this by adding this to your workspace's *.vscode/settings.json* file:
(or create it if it doesn't exist yet):

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "/path/to/your/python"
}
```

Then reload the window.

You can check that it's now using the correct interpreter by looking at the status bar at the bottom and by opening a new terminal:

[image]

For more info:

- [Using Python environments in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments)

Comment: Thanks, the readon was that I installed PyCharm and it messed with My windows Paths for Python 3.8.
After I fixed the windows paths and pointed them back to Python 3.8 it worked.

Comment: @BrunoSimões Well, with VS Code, you can always have multiple versions installed, and then you can just pick the one to use for a particular workspace.